# doc['field'].value never returning values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, kibana-6

Using Kibana/ Elasticsearch version 6.6.

Trying to run the below simple painless script:

```
String val = "Vanished"; 
if(doc.containsKey('type')) { 
    return doc['type'].value;
}
return val;
```

In the `Preview Results` section, when I try to run the code, the `First 10 results` section is always:

```
[]
```

However, if I alter the code like below:

```
String val = "Vanished"; 
if(doc.containsKey('type')) { 
    return "Present";
}
return val;
```

I am getting the below result in the same `Preview Results` section:

```
[
 {
  "_id": "Kha1NmkBcY4KotEKXsZz",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "1oS1NmkBjBc6pl9UX0IW",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "14S1NmkBjBc6pl9UX0IW",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "whC1NmkBCa8dRNQVXzEW",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "X221NmkBZQRXPOstYIHB",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "Rca1NmkBZrtXVVVdY50r",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "CMS1NmkBwiujVR8BZAt2",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "xhC1NmkBCa8dRNQVZTFf",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "yBC1NmkBCa8dRNQVZTFf",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "yRC1NmkBCa8dRNQVZTFf",
  "test112": [
   "Present"
  ]
 }
]
```

Can someone please help figure out why the `doc['type'].value` is failing?

Comment: Whats the mapping for `type`?

Comment: Its a `String`. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by changing the script to the below:

```
String val = "Vanished"; 
if(doc.containsKey('type.keyword')) { 
    return doc['type.keyword'].value;
}
return val;
```

Note the use of `type.keyword` instead of `type` as the field name.